# How to extract text after last occurrence of dash with regex?

Tags: java, regex

I use the following regex to extract artist name and song title from the full mp3 path:

```
.*\/(.*) +\- +(.*)\..*
```

It works well, when the file looks like `file\to\path\Artist Name - Song Title.mp3`, but it works incorrectly, when the filename contains several occurences of space-dash-space, like `Artist Name - With Dash - Song Title.mp3`. Is there any way to fix it with regex modification?

Comment: There is no way to tell if both the artist and the song name has dash.

Comment: Why not using `(.*)-(.*)\.mp3`?

Comment: @nhahtdh, of course. I wanted to assume that song name doesn't have it, my artist can have.

Answer (score 2):

```
^(?:.*\\)?(.*) +\- +(.*)\..*$
```

Try this.Grab the capture.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/wZ0iA3/7

Answer (score 0):

When changing the `\/` to `\\` in your original regex, it actually gives the **[correct result?](https://regex101.com/r/bG1hJ2/1)**

But I agree with nhahtdh that ultimately there's no way for a regular expression to know *"does this dash belong to the artist name? Or the song title? Or does it separate the two?"*

So when you ask *"Is there any way to fix it **with regex modification**?"* the answer is **no**.

Seeing as you tagged this Java, and lets say you have a database of known artists and songs, an approach could be to extract (any number of) strings that are separated by `-` and then find matching artist names by concatenating all but the last, if no match is found try again with one string fewer, etc.

This would be a way to extract all the `-` delimited strings:

```
(?!.*[\/\\])((?:(?! - ).)+)(?: - |\.mp3)
```

**[Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/zX2zJ2/1)**